# Retrofit kotlin how to write data class with specific variable name

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2

This is part of json file

```json
"list": {
"2023-01-12": [
  {
"patient_symptom_id": 10,
"date": "2023-01-12",
"datetime": "2023-01-12T11:11:11.000Z",
"symptom_list": [
  {
"symptom_id": 1,
"name": "Color",
"color": "#f4f50b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  3,
  4
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Clear",
  "Cloudy"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 2,
"name": "Energy",
"color": "#7ae38b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  27,
  42
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Anxious",
  "High"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 4,
"name": "Stool",
"color": "#f2b706",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  14,
  29
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Constipation (1-2)",
  "Unable to Pass"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 6,
"name": "General Symptoms",
"color": "#951af6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  31,
  34
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Fever",
  "Headache"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 7,
"name": "Urinary Symptoms",
"color": "#23a7f1",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  37
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Urgency when urinating"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 8,
"name": "Menstrual",
"color": "#f413d6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  45
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Light flow"
],
}
],
}
],
"2023-01-26": [
  {
"patient_symptom_id": 11,
"date": "2023-01-26",
"datetime": "2023-01-26T11:38:11.000Z",
"symptom_list": [
  {
"symptom_id": 1,
"name": "Color",
"color": "#f4f50b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  3,
  4
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Clear",
  "Cloudy"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 2,
"name": "Energy",
"color": "#7ae38b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  27,
  42
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Anxious",
  "High"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 4,
"name": "Stool",
"color": "#f2b706",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  14,
  29
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Constipation (1-2)",
  "Unable to Pass"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 6,
"name": "General Symptoms",
"color": "#951af6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  31,
  34
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Fever",
  "Headache"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 7,
"name": "Urinary Symptoms",
"color": "#23a7f1",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  37
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Urgency when urinating"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 8,
"name": "Menstrual",
"color": "#f413d6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  45
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Light flow"
],
}
],
},
  {
"patient_symptom_id": 12,
"date": "2023-01-26",
"datetime": "2023-01-26T11:38:11.000Z",
"symptom_list": [
  {
"symptom_id": 1,
"name": "Color",
"color": "#f4f50b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  3,
  4
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Clear",
  "Cloudy"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 2,
"name": "Energy",
"color": "#7ae38b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  27,
  42
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Anxious",
  "High"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 4,
"name": "Stool",
"color": "#f2b706",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  14,
  29
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Constipation (1-2)",
  "Unable to Pass"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 6,
"name": "General Symptoms",
"color": "#951af6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  31,
  34
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Fever",
  "Headache"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 7,
"name": "Urinary Symptoms",
"color": "#23a7f1",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  37
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Urgency when urinating"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 8,
"name": "Menstrual",
"color": "#f413d6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  45
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Light flow"
],
}
],
},
  {
"patient_symptom_id": 13,
"date": "2023-01-26",
"datetime": "2023-01-26T11:38:11.000Z",
"symptom_list": [
  {
"symptom_id": 1,
"name": "Color",
"color": "#f4f50b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  3,
  4
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Clear",
  "Cloudy"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 2,
"name": "Energy",
"color": "#7ae38b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  27,
  42
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Anxious",
  "High"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 4,
"name": "Stool",
"color": "#f2b706",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  14,
  29
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Constipation (1-2)",
  "Unable to Pass"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 6,
"name": "General Symptoms",
"color": "#951af6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  31,
  34
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Fever",
  "Headache"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 7,
"name": "Urinary Symptoms",
"color": "#23a7f1",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  37
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Urgency when urinating"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 8,
"name": "Menstrual",
"color": "#f413d6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  45
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Light flow"
],
}
],
},
  {
"patient_symptom_id": 80,
"date": "2023-01-26",
"datetime": "2023-01-26T11:11:11.000Z",
"symptom_list": [
  {
"symptom_id": 1,
"name": "Color",
"color": "#f4f50b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  6
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Low"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 2,
"name": "Energy",
"color": "#7ae38b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  27,
  42
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Anxious",
  "High"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 4,
"name": "Stool",
"color": "#f2b706",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  14,
  29
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Constipation (1-2)",
  "Unable to Pass"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 6,
"name": "General Symptoms",
"color": "#951af6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  31,
  34
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Fever",
  "Headache"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 7,
"name": "Urinary Symptoms",
"color": "#23a7f1",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  37
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Urgency when urinating"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 8,
"name": "Menstrual",
"color": "#f413d6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  45
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Light flow"
],
}
],
}
],
"2023-01-29": [
  {
"patient_symptom_id": 16,
"date": "2023-01-29",
"datetime": "2023-01-29T11:38:11.000Z",
"symptom_list": [
  {
"symptom_id": 1,
"name": "Color",
"color": "#f4f50b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  3,
  4
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Clear",
  "Cloudy"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 2,
"name": "Energy",
"color": "#7ae38b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  27,
  42
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Anxious",
  "High"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 4,
"name": "Stool",
"color": "#f2b706",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  14,
  29
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Constipation (1-2)",
  "Unable to Pass"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 6,
"name": "General Symptoms",
"color": "#951af6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  31,
  34
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Fever",
  "Headache"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 7,
"name": "Urinary Symptoms",
"color": "#23a7f1",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  37
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Urgency when urinating"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 8,
"name": "Menstrual",
"color": "#f413d6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  45
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Light flow"
],
}
],
},
  {
"patient_symptom_id": 17,
"date": "2023-01-29",
"datetime": "2023-01-29T11:38:11.000Z",
"symptom_list": [
  {
"symptom_id": 1,
"name": "Color",
"color": "#f4f50b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  1,
  6
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Low",
  "Yellow"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 2,
"name": "Energy",
"color": "#7ae38b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  27,
  42
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Anxious",
  "High"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 4,
"name": "Stool",
"color": "#f2b706",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  14,
  29
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Constipation (1-2)",
  "Unable to Pass"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 6,
"name": "General Symptoms",
"color": "#951af6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  31,
  34
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Fever",
  "Headache"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 7,
"name": "Urinary Symptoms",
"color": "#23a7f1",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  37
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Urgency when urinating"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 8,
"name": "Menstrual",
"color": "#f413d6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  45
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Light flow"
],
}
],
},
  {
"patient_symptom_id": 19,
"date": "2023-01-29",
"datetime": "2023-01-29T11:38:11.000Z",
"symptom_list": [
  {
"symptom_id": 1,
"name": "Color",
"color": "#f4f50b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  1,
  6
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Low",
  "Yellow"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 2,
"name": "Energy",
"color": "#7ae38b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  27,
  42
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Anxious",
  "High"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 4,
"name": "Stool",
"color": "#f2b706",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  14,
  29
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Constipation (1-2)",
  "Unable to Pass"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 6,
"name": "General Symptoms",
"color": "#951af6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  31,
  34
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Fever",
  "Headache"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 7,
"name": "Urinary Symptoms",
"color": "#23a7f1",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  37
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Urgency when urinating"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 8,
"name": "Menstrual",
"color": "#f413d6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  45
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Light flow"
],
}
],
},
  {
"patient_symptom_id": 20,
"date": "2023-01-29",
"datetime": "2023-01-29T11:38:11.000Z",
"symptom_list": [
  {
"symptom_id": 1,
"name": "Color",
"color": "#f4f50b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  1,
  6
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Low",
  "Yellow"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 2,
"name": "Energy",
"color": "#7ae38b",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  27,
  42
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Anxious",
  "High"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 4,
"name": "Stool",
"color": "#f2b706",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  14,
  29
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Constipation (1-2)",
  "Unable to Pass"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 6,
"name": "General Symptoms",
"color": "#951af6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  31,
  34
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Fever",
  "Headache"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 7,
"name": "Urinary Symptoms",
"color": "#23a7f1",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  37
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Urgency when urinating"
],
},
  {
"symptom_id": 8,
"name": "Menstrual",
"color": "#f413d6",
"symptom_value_ids": [
  45
],
"symptom_value_names": [
  "Light flow"
],
}
],
}
```

Inside the list, everything seems like a dictionary whose key is the date value is a List. When I write data class, I write in this way now:

```kotlin
data class Lists(
    val `2023-01-02`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-03`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-04`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-07`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-10`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-11`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-12`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-13`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-20`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-22`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-24`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-25`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-26`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-27`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-28`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-29`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-30`: List<SymptomList>,
    val `2023-01-31`: List<SymptomList>
)
```

I know it is not the good way, because there may be more item in dictionary, so what should I do to write the data class? I tried add one more layer named dictionary but it didn't work.

```kotlin
data class Dictionary(
    val dictionary: MutableMap<DateKey, List<SymptomList>>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please use online resource like [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) to validate and beautify your JSON String. It is not readable and also invalid.

---

Back to your question, yes, you should use `MutableMap` to store your list of Objects instead of creating tons of variables in your data class.

Consider the following example that should have *similar structure* with your JSON String:

```json
{
   "data":{
      "2022-12-20":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "name":"A"
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "name":"B"
         }
      ],
      "2022-12-21":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "name":"C"
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "name":"D"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

You should have the following data classes:

```kotlin
data class DataList(val data: MutableMap<String, List<SubData>>)
```

```kotlin
data class SubData(val id: Int, val name: String)
```

And you can use **Gson** library to convert your JSON String into your Object:

```kotlin
val dataList = Gson().fromJson(rawJson, DataList::class.java)
dataList.data.forEach { (key, value) ->
    println("Key: $key")
    println("Value: $value")
}
```

Output:

```
Key: 2022-12-20
Value: [SubData(id=1, name=A), SubData(id=2, name=B)]
Key: 2022-12-21
Value: [SubData(id=3, name=C), SubData(id=4, name=D)]
```